# Are irregular polygons constructible?

Tags: geometry, polygons, geometric-construction

I don't know if my question doesn't make sense or it's just too elementary but I can't seem to find something anywhere in internet that guides me to a precise answer, I mean, in my head it's completely possible but the lack of answers made me question if I'm overlooking something. Anyways, is it possible to construct an irregular polygon?

Comment: If and only if the coordinates of the points making up the polygon are also constructible, period.

Comment: Are you asking if, given a **specific** irregular polygon, is it always possible to construct that specific polygon?

Comment: Some are some aren't.  *regular* polygons  are not always constructable. I don't think a regular 9-gon is constructable.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, a nonagon can't be constructed, at least with only a compass and straightedge.

Comment: ... which is what "constructable" means.  My point (and yours too I believe) is regularity is not a determining factor in constructability. Your point is good.  A polygonal is contructable iff the vertices are.  I guess in general "constructable polygon" usually implies regular but that's probably just convention.  Several right triangles, irregular rectangles parallelagrams, polygons of 1 line length to others with constructable angles are obviously constructible.  But there's no point in distinguishing them as "constructable polygons" as that would make the phrase meaningless.

Comment: @tilper I'm asking about in general, if there are irregular polygons that can be constructed. 
As I said I was assuming this was the case as it's pretty logical, but while I was trying to learn more about this, there was **no** mention of anything besides regular polygons.

Comment: @fleablood This is what I was looking for, since there was no reference to anything outside regular polygons (and not even all regular polygons are constructible) while looking for more info, I couldn't assume if it was just convention or there was something else that I overlooked.

Comment: The more I think about it the more sense "constructable polygons" means regular polygons that are constructable.  Anything with coordinates that are constructable numbers is constructable so that will of course include several irregular polygons.  (Any right triangle with integer sides, for example). So constructible irregular polygons is simply not an interesting question. A more interesting question is which regular polygons are constructible i.e. when will the vertices of a regular polygon be constructible. (Answer: when $n=2^k\prod p_i$ where $p_i$ are distinct mercenne primes, apparently)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes they can be and sometimes they can't.

For example, as you probably know, it is possible to construct a square and it is possible to construct an equilateral triangle.  It is not too difficult, then, to construct the following 'house':

[image]

However, it is impossible to contruct this polygon, built from a regular heptagon:

[image]

Why is it impossible?  Well, if we could construct that figure, then we could bisect the angle called $2a$ and construct the dotted line.  Then we would have constructed a regular heptagon.  But this is known to be impossible, [since $7$ is prime and not of the form $2^{2^N}+1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon).

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't really make sense as long as you don't specify *which* irregular polygon.

The vast majority of polygons aren't constructible. For examples, consider the polygon with an angle equal to an angle of a non-constructible regular polygon, or polygons with sides in a transcendental ratio.